# ZF2 Form and Doctirine Error

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, service-locator

I try to use ZF2 Form and Doctirine. But i take an error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message '$initializer should be callable.' in C:\Projects\eperde\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php on line" My Form class path is true. It's Admin\Form\CategoryForm.

Could you help me? What's the problem?

```
public function getFormElementConfig(){

    return array(
        'initializers' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
                'CategoryForm' => 'Admin\Form\CategoryForm',
            ),
            'ObjectManagerInitializer' => function ($element, $formElements) {
                    if ($element instanceof ObjectManagerAwareInterface) {

                        $services      = $formElements->getServiceLocator();
                        $entityManager = $services->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
                        $element->setObjectManager($entityManager);
                    }
                },
        ),
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty much what you want to do:

Create an alias for `categoryform` to point at `Admin\Form\CategoryForm`.
Add an initializer to inject the ObjectManager. I think a factory would be a much more elegant way to do this!

module.config.php (or `Module::getConfig()`):

```
'form_elements' => array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'categoryform' => 'Admin\Form\CategoryForm',
    ),
    'initializers' => array(
        'ObjectManagerInitializer' => function ($element, $pluginManager) {
            if ($element instanceof \DoctrineModule\Persistence\ObjectManagerAwareInterface) {
                $serviceLocator = $pluginManager->getServiceLocator();
                $entityManager = $serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

                $element->setObjectManager($entityManager);
            }
        },
    ),
),
```